# Get the current language of the application not the device Android

Tags: android, android-configchanges

So I'am using a button to switch language from english to french !

My problem is that i need to know the language of my current Application only not the language of my device .

I'am using these line of code in order to know the current language

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

but Apparently he's returning my device language .

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12530405/6371926