# "getDisplayLanguage()" always returning "English"

Tags: android

I need to get the current language selected in the Android device. When I use below code:

```
Log.v("Language: ", Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
Log.v("Language: ", getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayLanguage());
```

The output is always same:

```
V/Language:: English
```

Below picture from android emulator selected language:

[image: android emulator selected language]

When I change the language of emulator, I can get the logs in the picture on the Android console.(But getDisplayLanguage() function returning English)

[image: android console]

Comment: Locale.getDefault() always return english because default of android language is english ;) remove getDefault() and check it

Answer (score 1):

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
String locale = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
```

They are different. The first can change if the user switches the Locale.

The second is the one that is pre-installed on the phone. It never changes no matter what the user does.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: My result hasn't changed. If you tried it and it works correctly, the error is probably in my emulator.

Comment: Kindly refer this,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690460/how-to-get-language-locale-currently-android-app-displays

Hope this helps you... :)