# How do "Locale.getDefault()" and "getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)" work exactly?

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

My app (Java 11, min: API 29, target: API 30 = Android 11) currently supports two languages: German (default) & English

The "build.gradle(Module:app)" file contains `resConfigs("de", "en")` and there are two `strings.xml` files with the translations.

According to the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#getDefault(java.util.Locale.Category)), `Locale.getDefault()` should return:

> the current value of the default locale for the specified Category for this instance of the Java Virtual Machine.

If I understand this correctly, then this is the `Locale` currently being used by the app.

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#getLocales()) for `getLocales()` only say:

> Get the locale list. This is the preferred way for getting the locales (instead of using the direct accessor to locale, which would only provide the primary locale).

... but according to multiple threads, this function is also supposed to return the `Locale` that's currently being used by the app. I want to know which language this is, so I did some testing with the following print:

```
Log.d(TAG,"1="+Locale.getDefault()+", 2="+getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0));
```

- Set the emulator to "English (US)" -> English is chosen correctly, prints "1=en_US, 2=en_US"
- German (CH) -> German is chosen correctly, prints "1=de_CH, 2=de_CH"
- German + English (US) -> German is chosen correctly, prints "1=de_CH, 2=de_CH"
- Danish + German (CH) -> German is chosen correctly, prints "1=de_CH, 2=de_CH"
- Danish + English (US) -> English is chosen correctly, prints "1=en_US, 2=en_US"
- Danish + Italian -> German is chosen correctly, prints "1=da_DK, 2=da_DK"
- Italian + Spanish -> German is chosen correctly, prints "1=in_IT, 2=in_IT"

It looks like they are either set to the language that is both supported by the app and chosen in Android's settings by the user OR the first language chosen by the user if none of them are supported by the app.

My app's got a spinner that changes the language. Calling e.g. `Locale.setDefault(Locale.English)` switches everything to English but if I switch from the first activity to the second, then this value is reset. E.g.:

German + English (US) -> German is chosen automatically (prints "1=de_CH, 2=de_CH") -> switch to English -> UI elements switch too -> switch activity -> prints "1=de_CH, 2=en" in `onCreateView`, while all the UI elements are in English; with Danish + Italian it prints "1=da_DK, 2=en"

I'm aware that `getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)` requires a call to `onConfigurationChanged` to change, while `Locale.setDefault()` applies the change instantly but why did the latter reset all of a sudden? Why did I get the results I got during my tests, instead of the `Locale` currently in use? How do you get a reliable result for the `Locale` the app actually uses (it can't just be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691091/2016165), right?)?

Or better: How do both of these functions actually work? Are they simply buggy?

The docs don't mention any of this but only how the `Locale` is chosen on app start ([here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support)) and the [latest changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) to the language preferences only apply to Android 13+.

Comment: after u make language switch ....  did u make a full restart for the app ?

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh No, that's not necessary if you do it in `onConfigurationChanged`. Any idea why what's happening is happening?

Comment: Locale and Resources.Configuration.locale are not returning the resources that are truly used by the app, but the setting of the phone. I do not think there is official API to check what app resources locale is accessed, as it is complex logic and you can have partial resources for any of the languages in multiple configurations.

Comment: @V-master How do you explain the "en_US" output when the phone is set to Danish (-> Android UI is in Danish) with English as its second language? It seems to be a weird mix, depending on if any of the listed languages are supported by the app or if it has to fall back to the default. And then there's that weird changed value after switching activity.

Comment: @V-master Regarding partial resources: Android Studio complains if a certain string doesn't appear in every "string.xml" files, which makes this hard to miss by accident, and who would not translate their full app on purpose? Even if that's actually the case, it should (afaik) fall back to the default language. `getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales()` returns a `List`, so there already is a way to output multiple locales, it's just that the docs aren't helpful and the test results seem to vary for some weird reason (btw, my app is fully translated).

Comment: translations are not the only resources that can be language dependent, drawablec, booleans, integeres, all resources can be locale dependant. Back to your original question the locales returned by both apis are the locales of the device, and if you do not have given locale resources it doesn't matter, it will return it as it is. If you want to have info of which is currently displayed to the user than you would need (as you had found) special translated resource that will contain language identification and be sure to translate it with all other string resources

Comment: @V-master You're correct, both functions return the language the app picked from the user's preferences but Android handles them in different ways. I did some more testing and I'm going to post the results as an answer. Please feel free to comment on it if you've got more information.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing with my language `Spinner` (dropdown menu in the first activity):

**A**. `Locale.getDefault()` returns the device's language the app chose to use and it resets every time you switch activity (it doesn't seem to change if you switch between fragments!). In my tests `Locale.setDefault` didn't affect any `TextView`s, `EditText`s or other UI elements (except: see below).

**B**. `getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)` returns the same language but the changes you apply with `onConfigurationChanged` "stick", even after switching activity. It affects at least `TextView`s, `EditText`s, `Switch`es and `Button`s (again, see below) but the changes are only applied if you call it before you inflate the view, refresh the view after or if you override `onConfigureChanged`.

Sounds decently straight forward but it's not. Let's look at an example and let's also add a `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` (in activity 2) to the equation:

- The app supports: German and English
- Languages in Android settings: 1. English, 2. German
- The app starts in English, as that is the user's preferred language. Both A and B print "en_US".
- Switch to German, using the spinner in the first activity (with `onConfigurationChanged`). Both A and B print "de_CH".
- Switch to the second activity. A prints "en_US" because it was reset to the user's preferred language, while B kept the change I applied manually in the first activity and prints "de_CH". All the `TextView`s are in German but the DatePicker and TimePicker are still in English.

To change the language of both pickers, you have to use A (e.g. `Locale.setDefault(getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0))` - looks easy but there's another catch, see below) right at the start of `onCreateView`, before you even inflate the view and before you call e.g. `datePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker)`. Afterwards both A and B print "de_CH" again and the pickers are in German.

This works the same way if the Android device is set to e.g. Danish + English: English is picked automatically and B remembers a switch to German even in the second activity.

I have not been able to get it to fully work with `DatePickerDialog` but that's a [different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21257014/2016165).

To get back to the other, more complicated, example: Danish + Italian

The app correctly starts in German, both A and B print "da_DK". Without changing the language in-app using the spinner, the pickers in activity 2 are now in Danish. If I change the language via the dropdown menu before switching activity, then the pickers use the correct language that was chosen (because the spinner set B to that specific language and B remembered it).

**What to take away from this:**

Don't rely on A or B, unless you can be absolutely sure that the user's phone uses at least one of the languages your app supports. Sadly it seems to really be best to just use the solution that was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691091/2016165): Add a key-value pair with the code for that specific language to your localization files, check it after app start, then set up a `Locale` for that language, change and update it accordingly by hand, pass it around between activities and use it when needed (e.g. for a DatePicker).